# how can I get Django-ajax popup button to work?

Tags: ajax, django, popup

I am trying to create a popup form for a New Task in my calendar, but I have never get it to work. I am using Ajax for this purpose. Here is my code. The Ajax is located in the static folder under the name "plugin.js"

base.py

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bookstore</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/plugin.js' %}"></script>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

calendar.html

```
{% extends 'cal/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Quality Assurance Calendar
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-form">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      New Task
    </button>

{% endif %}


</div>

{{ calendar }}

<div class="modal-fad" id="modal-task">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

part of the view.py

```
    def task_create(request, task_id=None):
    # if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    #     return redirect('%s?next=%s' % ('account/login/', request.path))
    instance = Task()
    if task_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
    else:
        instance = Task()

    form = TaskForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    # form.user = request.user
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        # form = form.save(commit=False)
        # form.user = request.user
        form.save()
    #     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:calendar'))
    # return render(request, 'cal/task_create.html', {'form': form})
    html_form=render_to_string('cal/task_create.html', {'form': form}, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'html_form':html_form})
```

And the plugin.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-form').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/task/create',
            type: 'get',
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#modal-task').modal('show');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#modal-task .modal-content').html(data.html_form);
            }
    })

})
```

task_create.html

```
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<button class="btn btn-primary show-form" data-url="{% url 'cal:task_create' %}"></button>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Create Task</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-lable ="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="True">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>

        {{ form|crispy}}
        <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

The new task button has never responded!!!
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: Did you verify that the click handler is being called? If it is, then does the request to `/task/create` get made? If it does, how does that respond? When debugging, pick a place to start, typically from one end and start eliminating possibilities while avoiding making any assumptions.

Comment: what does "has never responded" mean? do you see the modal? or nothing at all? Also your form is in the modal, so you can't pop up the modal in your ajax call. You should just open the modal. And when the user submits the form (`.on('submit')`) do the ajax call. Which should be a POST not a GET.

Comment: Your button has nothing written in it, it will appear as just a small box, how do you even click on that. If you are somehow able to click it, then inside the click handler add a `console.log` to make sure the function is running when the button is clicked. If it's working write some console.log inside the success or fail of ajax call to make sure it's getting the proper data from server. That's how you debug js code, add a lot of console logs to figure out what part of code is running when. Don't forget to remove them when the problem is fixed.

Comment: Also you are trying to put the html received from ajax call in `#modal-task .modal-content` but no such element exists in your html and I don't think jquery raises any error in situations like these, it just goes whatever.

Comment: when I click  nothing happen at all.

Comment: I tried most of these suggestion, but still stuck. I have a feeling it is just a small thing that I have not figured out yet.

Comment: Now the New task button look like that:<button class="btn btn-primary show-form" data-url="{% url 'cal:task_create' %}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  New task
  </button> but still no winning!

Answer (score 0):

sorted out.
I have got all what i need in this tutorial
Here is the link (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

thanks to all for the valuable comments.